# How to deliver user input in Entry fields in tkinter to external classes/methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am a novice Python programmer trying to write a compact GUI using Tkinter that will run a program that outputs a MS Excel file with a full loan amortization given the parameters entered in the GUI. My current issue is that every time I do enter input into the Entry fields and press the button that is supposed to create the file, it doesn't create a file with the title that I have entered, or any information thereafter. I can tell that whatever input is being put into the fields is not making it into the method that writes the .xlsx file.

I've tried rewriting the program several times, including working off of templates I found on the internet, and taking suggestions from older Stack Exchange forums. Important to note is that I have currently only implemented payments on a monthly basis into the code, so anytime the "Payments per year" input is filled out, it should be filled with 12.

Here is some of the relevant code.

```py
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


class Loan():
    def __init__(self, payments_per_year):
        self.payments_per_year = payments_per_year


class ExcelFile():
    def __init__(self, file_name, loan):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.loan = loan

    def createFile(self):
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(self.file_name + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet(self.file_name)

        worksheet.write('A1', 'Payments/year:')
        worksheet.write('B1', self.loan.payments_per_year)


class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.master = master
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):

        mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.master)
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

        ttk.Label(mainframe, text='Payments/yr: ').grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=E)
        self.payments_per_year = IntVar()
        payments_per_year_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=self.payments_per_year)
        payments_per_year_entry.grid(column=3, row=6, sticky=(W, E))

        loan = Loan(self.payments_per_year)
        excel_file = ExcelFile('Test name', loan)

        create_xlsx_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Create Excel File",
                                        command=lambda: excel_file.createFile())
        create_xlsx_button.grid(column=3, row=10, sticky=(W, E))

def run_program():
    root = Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_program()
```

I expect to be able to input into the GUI and receive output in the form of an .xlsx file with the specified title and a payment-by-payment loan amortization. What I actually recieve is a .xlsx file titled '.xlsx' with no data.

Comment: Please try to reduce this down to a [mcve]. You've posted a lot of code that is unnecessary to reproduce the problem. For example, if you're getting no data at all, we only need one data field to know if the value was saved or not. All of the other input fields and labels aren't needed to solve this problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley thank you for the advice. I've made some edits to the posted code. Let me know if this is more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

GUI doesn't wait for user's data. And all in `__init__` is executed at program's start so now you get values from entries at program's start when entries are empty.

You have to get values from entries in function which you run with `Button`

```
def __init__(...):

    create_xlsx_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Create Excel File", command=self.save_data)


def save_data(self):
    self.initial_amount = self.initial_amount.get()
    self.interest_rate = self.interest_rate.get() / 100.00
    self.lifetime = self.lifetime.get()
    # issue_datetime = datetime.datetime(issue_year.get(), issue_day.get(), issue_year.get())
    self.issue_datetime = datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    self.payments_per_year = self.payments_per_year.get()
    self.file_name = self.file_name.get()

    loan = Loan(self.initial_amount, self.interest_rate, self.lifetime, self.issue_datetime, self.payments_per_year)
    excel_file = ExcelFile(self.file_name, loan)
    excel_file.createFile()
```